# How to Target Element In Modal After Opening Modal

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, asynchronous, modal, queryselector

I have a custom modal component (with slots) that can be opened and closed. In a parent component I'm using this modal component and inside the body slot of the modal I have a `<lightning-input>` - I'm trying to target this input immediately after opening the modal, but am having trouble.

The modal has a simple mechanism to open it, which is an `@api openModal()` method on the component that simply sets a property `isOpen` to true, and then in the html, the modal only shows if `isOpen` is true:

```
<!-- modal.html -->
<template>
    <template if:true={isOpen}>
        <!-- content here... -->
    </template>
</template>
```

In the parent component, I'm trying to open the modal, and then target the input element inside the modal so that I can select (highlight) the text. The parent component code looks something like this:

```
<!-- parent.html -->
<lightning-button label="Open Modal" onclick={openModalAndSelectInput}></lightning-button>
<c-modal data-id="modal">
    <div slot="body">
        <lightning-input type="text" label="Input Element" value="Some Text" data-id="inputElem"></lightning-input>
    </div>
</c-modal>
```

and

```
// parent.js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
    openModalAndSelectInput() {
        // open modal
        const modalElem = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="modal"]');
        modalElem.openModal();

        // get input inside modal
        const inputElem = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="inputElem"]');
        inputElem.shadowRoot.querySelector('input').select();
    }
}
```

However, `inputElem` here (2nd to last line of code) is null, and I'm pretty sure the problem is that when I call `openModal()`, the UI won't actual update while synchronous JavaScript is still running, so the input element I'm trying to get doesn't exist in the DOM yet. That problem is described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767722/how-to-show-css-loader-while-syncronous-javascript-is-running). One solution is to use a `setTimeout` to essentially force the JavaScript to run asynchronously.

**Is there a better solution in the Salesforce LWC context than to use `setTimeout`?**

[Here is sample code](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/9BpB3NqbdWPSyp1pFPd7) that includes 2 different open methods, one that uses setTimeout and works, and another that doesn't.

Comment: You can fire an event from modal to Parent component from “openModal” method that its execution finished. In the parent component then you can be sure that child dom rendered and can start querying. I remember running into similar problem with Aura as well.

Comment: @javanoob - unfortunately even if you trigger a custom event, it still has the same issue b/c the javascript is running synchronously. I tried your suggestion by adding a custom 'open' event to the modal child and doing an `onopen` in the parent, but same error: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/9BpB3NqbdWPSyp1pFPd7

Comment: Looks like rendering isn't complete by the time event is fired. I thought this would happen after the rendering is finished. Anyway, you can fire event from `renderedCallback` lifecycle hook method and that should resolve it. Here is the one I was able to come up with: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/pKprb6dckdX4RSDublOa

Comment: Ah, nice - I'm going to give this a try in my actual project to see if it works in context. I would think you'd probably want to set `this.firedModalOpenedEvent` back to false in the `closeModal()` method.

Comment: Strangely it works in webcomponents.dev, but not in the environment I'm developing in. The issue seems not to be with the timing of the rendering, but something else. B/c I actually tried adding a button in the modal itself that will select the input text on click. In that click handler, when I set `const elem = this.template.querySelector('...')` and set a breakpoint, I can see elem returns a Proxy, `elem.value` returns the value of the input, so it seems to be targeting the input. But setting `elem.selectionStart/End` doesn't do anything, and `elem.shadowRoot` returns `undefined`. So...??